# Change storageBucket ref after initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to build a storage manager app for Firebase Storage in React.

The app should be able to list/add/delete buckets and files inside them.

I have my `initializeApp` set up as follows

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'buckettest-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'buckettest-xxxxx',
  storageBucket: 'buckettest-xxxxx.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  measurementId: 'G-QZDBHEWHJ5',
});

const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

So far so good. The config works, the `storage` is connected to the storage bucket from the config `storageBucket: 'buckettest-xxxxx.appspot.com',`

Upload, download, view, delete functionalities work perfect.

The problem is that if I switch to a different bucket from my app, the `storage` object is still bound to the `buckettest-xxxxx.appspot.com` from the config.

How can I change the bucket so that I can upload to other buckets as well?

Assume I have the following list of buckets:

- buckettest-xxxxx.appspot.com
- buckettest-yyyyy.appspot.com
- buckettest-zzzzz.appspot.com

How can I switch the `storage` object to use the `buckettest-zzzzz.appspot.com` after the init?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a new `FirebaseApp` object initialized to the new bucket, and then get the `storage()` service from that.

```
var otherApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  storageBucket: 'otherbucket.appspot.com',
}, second);
var otherStorage = otherApp.storage();
```

Comment: I thought of this, but given the fact that I can create buckets, delete them and so on... creating more fireBaseApps would be a memory issue at some point? 

Is there a way to destroy this instances maybe?

Comment: "at some point" These objects are quite lightweight. Unless you creating tens of thousands of them, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also have a follow up question regarding auth between apps now... maybe you can take a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65287720/authenticate-users-between-firebase-apps