# Authenticate users between firebase apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a React app with firebase auth and storage

Following on my previous question with multiple firebase apps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280088/change-storagebucket-ref-after-initialization/65280197#65280197), I ended having multiple `firebase` apps inside my project.

I have the `DEFAULT` app initialized

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'buckettest-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'buckettest-xxxxx',
  storageBucket: 'buckettest-xxxxx.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  measurementId: 'G-QZDBHEWHJ5',
});
```

Users log in with email and password, using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method from `firebase.auth()` from the `DEFAULT` app above

In a component I create a secondary firebase app that connects to a different storage bucket as follows

```js
const createStoreApp = (bucket) => {
  const firebaseStoreApp = firebase.apps.length === 1
    ? firebase.initializeApp({
      storageBucket: bucket.name,
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      authDomain: 'buckettest-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
      projectId: 'buckettest-xxxxx',
      storageBucket: 'buckettest-xxxxx.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      measurementId: 'G-QZDBHEWHJ5',
    }, 'storage')
    : firebase.apps[1];

  return firebaseStoreApp;
};
```

This solution works perfectly BUT there is the issue that there is no autheticated user on this secondary app.

Is there a way to autheticate the `currentUser` from the `DEFAULT` app instance to the second one without asking for credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each initialized app instance has its own authentication.  You can't have one app instance reach into another app to get its auth data.   As such, you will need to use the Firebase Auth APIs to sign in the user in to the second app instance separately.  Since you're using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, it sounds like you're going to have to store the user's credentials somewhere until you're able to call `initializeApp` again with them as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't there any other auth method? I saw that there is a token login method can't I issue a token that is valid for auth? Storing the password in the front end doesn't seem to orthodox

Comment: If you want a custom token signin, you'll need to involve a backend that issues a token for the user using the Firebase Admin SDK.  So your client app will need to invoke this backend to request a custom token, and use that to sign in to the other app instance.  The documentation for that is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a better approach to the issue at hand